# Trouble with overloaded constructors and variable passing

Tags: c++, constructor

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <string>


 class Date
 {
   public:
    Date(int, int, int);
    Date(std::string, int, int);
    void print();
    void printFullDate();
    int getMonth();
    int getDay();
    int getYear();
    void setMonth(int);
    void setDay(int);
    void setYear(int);


    private:
    int mm,dd,yy;
    std::string mstr;

 };
```

This is my header file for the class Date

Below is the implementation

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Date.h"

using namespace std;

Date::Date(int mm, int dd, int yy)
{
    if(mm < 1 || mm > 12 )
     {
        cout << "Please Enter a Valid Month (1-12)";
        cin >> mm;
     }

    if(mm == 1 || mm == 3 || mm == 5 || mm == 7 || mm == 8 || mm == 10 || mm == 12)
        {
            if(dd < 1 || dd > 31)
            {
                cout << "Please Enter a Valid Date For the Month Entered(1-31)";
                cin >> dd;
            }
        }

    if(mm == 4 || mm == 6 || mm == 9 || mm == 11)
    {
        if(dd < 1 || dd >30)
        {
            cout << "Please Enter a Valid Date for the Month Entered(1-30)";
            cin >> dd;
        }
    }

    if ( (yy % 4 == 0 && yy % 100 != 0) || ( yy % 400 == 0))
    {
        if(mm == 2)
        {
            if( dd < 1 || dd > 29)
            {
                cout << "Please Enter a Valid Date for the Month Entered(1-29)";
                cin >> dd;
            }
        }


    }
    else 
    {
        if(mm == 2)
        {
            if(dd < 1 || dd > 28)
            {
                cout << "Please Enter a Valid Date for the Month Entered(1-28)";
                cin >> dd;
            }
        }
    }   

    if (yy < 1)
    {
        cout << "Please Enter a Valid Date of the era AD";
        cin >> yy;
    }

    switch(mm) 
    {
        case 1:
        mstr = "January";
        break;

        case 2:
        mstr = "February";
        break;

        case 3:
        mstr = "March";
        break;

        case 4:
        mstr = "April";
        break;

        case 5:
        mstr = "May";
        break;

        case 6:
        mstr = "June";
        break;

        case 7:
        mstr = "July";
        break;

        case 8:
        mstr = "August";
        break;

        case 9:
        mstr = "September";
        break;

        case 10:
        mstr = "October";
        break;

        case 11:
        mstr = "November";
        break;

        case 12:    
        mstr = "December";
        break;

    }


}

Date::Date(string mstr, int dd, int yy)
{

}

void Date::print()
{
    cout << "MM/DD/YYYY: " << mm << "/" << dd << "/" << yy << endl;
}

void Date::printFullDate()
{
    cout << "Month DD, YYYY: " << mstr << " " << dd << ", " << yy << endl;
    cout << "**********" << endl << endl;
}

void Date::setDay(int day)
{
    dd = day;
}

void Date::setMonth(int month)
{
    mm = month;
}

void Date::setYear(int year)
{
    yy = year;
}

int Date::getDay()
{
    return dd;
}

int Date::getMonth()
{
    return mm;
}

int Date::getYear()
{
    return yy;
}
```

When I call the function Date(int,int,int) it runs through everything just fine. However, when I call the print function the variables do not retain the values assigned in the constructor. When the constructor corrects a month, day, or year, that data is not output on print. Instead the original unchanged values are output. I believe that the variables once passed to the constructor should remain the same for the whole class.  I am lost. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: you are using the same names for your constructor parameters and your class fields. Change the names of the parameters so that they don't shadow your objet fields.

Comment: you are only assigning `mstr`, not the instance's `mm`, `yy`, `dd`. Once an input value passes your tests, you need to assign the instance's variables. Such as `this.mm = mm;` right after the parameter mm is validated. Better yet, rename the parameters being passed in, and you'll see it much better in code.

Answer (score 1):

That's because your constructor's parameters...

```
Date::Date(int mm, int dd, int yy)
```

...are distinct variables from the class member variables with the same names.  I normally name the members with a trailing underscore, e.g. `mm_, dd_, yy_` - then at the end of your constructor you can assign to them as in...

```
mm_ = mm; dd_ = dd; yy_ = yy; mstr_ = mstr;
```

Comment: Why not in the ctor-init-list, it's just for that? Ah, forget it, he's doing too many funky things in his ctor.

Comment: @Deduplicator - yeah - I was a bit shocked.... O_o